# Clustering huge high dimension vector

Tags: cluster-analysis, dimension

I have a huge dataset, the dataset contains more than 10,000 vectors, and each vector is now 252 dimensions and before I proceed further, because I am not from the domain of Machine Learning nor Math. I have some questions to ask:

1.I want to reduce dimension of each vector, but I don't know which algorithm to select.

2.Is KD-Tree a good choice for this?

Comment: 10.000 is not "huge". In fact, for a 252 dimensional space it is quite low, and your clustering results may become arbitrary because of this. A 252 x 252 matrix has 63.504 cells.
Have you tried without dimensionality reduction and index? How long did it take?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go ahead, and **try** different dimension reduction techniques. There is no general best, you will need to **try** out things.
2. K-d-tree will usually not work well with 252 dimensions. Because it's designed for Euclidean and Manhattan distance, and these are not too meaningful in 252 dimensions.

But with just 10000 instances, you probably don't need an index at all. That is tiny. 10000 * 252 * 8 bytes = 20 MB, that is not a lot. It will easily fit into main memory.

Comment: Thank you very much, those days I found that my dataset may contains more than 300,000 vectors. I read many documents that they suggested use KNN to classify the vectors.Could you give me more advice about to deal with it?

Comment: I just tried KNN algorithm, but the computing time is more than 30mins.

Comment: Yes, kNN classification is known to not scale well with data set size. Sometimes you can get decent results on samples though. The most popular methods these days seem to be random forests and SVM. But it really depends on your data what works, there is no "one size fits all".